# How do I use the random numbers I generated in a for loop, outside the for loop?

Tags: java

I want to generate 10 random numbers in a for loop. Then, I want to use these numbers outside the for loop. How do I do this?

```java
Random rand = new Random();

for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
    int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(10);
}

System.out.println(rand_int1);
```

This is my code. I am generating the numbers and printing them. But I don't understand how I would use them outside the loop. Do I create an array?

Comment: `I want to generate 10 random numbers in a for loop. Then, I want to use these numbers outside the for loop. How do I do this?` - You need to study [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 3):

This exercise is one of the most basic ones you need to understand when learning to code. Just let this code sink into your brain and understand its process.

```
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    
    int count = 10; // count generated numbers

    int[] randomnumbers = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(10);
        randomnumbers[i] = rand_int1;
        System.out.println(rand_int1);
    }

    // outside number generation loop usage
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println(randomnumbers[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is by creating a global collection variable before the loop and then you can operate on this outside the loop.

```
 List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
 Random rand = new Random(); 
          
 for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
     int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(10);
     nums.add(rand_int1); 
               
     System.out.println(rand_int1);
 }

 nums.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I believe this is a very clean and efficient solution. Due to use of libraries tho I think its a little bit too confusing for a guy with this knowledge in coding.

Comment: Maybe ... I think so in this case when someone is fresh in java your arrays approach @FunnyO could be better to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an array before the loop:

`int[] nums = new int[10];`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you are trying is to create a array of numbers and then put into that array 10 random numbers.To create an array in Java are multiples ways, but the most simple way is with this structure you have to use the structure:

```
<array_name> []; ej// 
 int my_Array[];
```

Now you have to initialize the array variable with the size if it:

```
<array_name> = new [size];
```

Now you can use that size to put in each array space a random number in your loop.

```
int[] my_array = new int[10]

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int rand_Int1 = rand.nextInt(10);
  my_array[i] = rand_Int1;
  System.out.println(rand_Int1);
}
```